# VBA Mailmerge to pdf Output

Tags: excel, mailmerge, vba

Good Morning
I have modified the code from this post: [Automating Mail Merge using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585226/automating-mail-merge-using-excel-vba)

But I only want pdf output but as soon as I take out the word code, it baulks. I think the problem is that if I don't save it as word, it doesn't shut the template down properly (there is code to close it). I have to manually click "Don't Save" and then it chokes as it tries to reopen the file for the next line. Any idea how to get around that? - Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

```
Public Sub MailMergeCert()
Dim bCreatedWordInstance As Boolean
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objMMMD As Word.Document

Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim Training As String
Dim SeminarDate As String
Dim HoursComp As String
Dim Location As String
Dim Objectives As String
Dim Trainer As String


Dim r As Long
Dim ThisFileName As String

'Your Sheet names need to be correct in here
Set sh1 = Sheets("Periop")

lastrow = Sheets("Periop").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
r = 2

For r = 2 To lastrow
If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 10).Value) = False Then GoTo nextrow

FirstName = sh1.Cells(r, 1).Value
LastName = sh1.Cells(r, 2).Value
Training = sh1.Cells(r, 3).Value
SeminarDate = sh1.Cells(r, 4).Value
HoursComp = sh1.Cells(r, 5).Value
Location = sh1.Cells(r, 6).Value
Objectives = sh1.Cells(r, 7).Value
Trainer = sh1.Cells(r, 8).Value

SeminarDate = Format(sh1.Cells(r, 4).Value, "d mmmm YYYY")


' Setup filenames
Const WTempName = "Certificate_Periop_2016.docx" 'Template name

' Setup directories
cDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" 'Change if required
ThisFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name

On Error Resume Next

' Create a Word Application instance
bCreatedWordInstance = False
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

If objWord Is Nothing Then
  Err.Clear
  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  bCreatedWordInstance = True
End If

If objWord Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Could not start Word"
Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
End If

' Let Word trap the errors
On Error GoTo 0

' Set to True if you want to see the Word Doc flash past during construction
objWord.Visible = False

'Open Word Template
Set objMMMD = objWord.Documents.Open(cDir + WTempName)
objMMMD.Activate

'Merge the data
With objMMMD
.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=cDir + ThisFileName, sqlstatement:="SELECT *  FROM `Periop$`"   ' Set this as required

With objMMMD.MailMerge  'With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
.SuppressBlankLines = True
With .DataSource
  .FirstRecord = r - 1
  .LastRecord = r - 1
  .ActiveRecord = r - 1
  ' EmployeeName = .EmployeeName
End With
.Execute Pause:=False
End With
End With

' Save new file
'Path and YYMM
Dim PeriopCertPath As String
PeriopCertPath = "C:\Users\305015724\Documents\ApplicationsTraining\2016\Periop\"
Dim YYMM As String
YYMM = Format(sh1.Cells(r, 11).Value, "YYMM")

'Word document
Dim NewFileNameWd As String
NewFileNameWd = YYMM & "_" & sh1.Cells(r, 12).Value & "_" & sh1.Cells(r, 2).Value & ".docx" 'Change File Name as req'd"
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=PeriopCertPath & NewFileNameWd

'PDF
Dim NewFileNamePDF As String
NewFileNamePDF = YYMM & "_" & sh1.Cells(r, 12).Value & "_" & sh1.Cells(r, 2).Value '& ".pdf" 'Change File Name as req'd"
objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat PeriopCertPath & NewFileNamePDF, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

' Close the Mail Merge Main Document
objMMMD.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set objMMMD = Nothing

' Close the New Mail Merged Document
If bCreatedWordInstance Then
objWord.Quit
End If

0:
Set objWord = Nothing
Cells(r, 10).Value = Date
nextrow:

Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I recorded saving a workbook as a pdf and this is the output:

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Doc1.pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, _
    OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:= _
    wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, _
    IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:= _
    wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:= _
    True, UseISO19005_1:=False
```

It seems like you might try:

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat PeriopCertPath & NewFileNamePDF,
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

The pdf generation always worked and I think I now have the Word bit sorted as well. This is the part of the code that generates the pdf and then closes Word (and a few other things ...)

```
'Print Certificate
'Print required
If sh1.Cells(r, 12) = "print" Then
    'remove background image
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Cut
    'Print Certificate
   objWord.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    'Close the Mail Merge Main Document
    objWord.ActiveDocument.Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
    objMMMD.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Set objMMMD = Nothing
Else
    'Close the Mail Merge Main Document
    objWord.ActiveDocument.Close (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
    objMMMD.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Set objMMMD = Nothing
End If

' Create a Word Application instance
bCreatedWordInstance = False
Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
' Close the New Mail Merged Document
If bCreatedWordInstance Then
    objWord.Quit
End If

0:
Set objWord = Nothing
```